# Disable hover animation in Wordpress Elementor in media queries

Tags: wordpress, animation, hover, opacity, elementor

I need to disable a hover animation built in Wordpress Elementor when the width in a media query is below a certain value.

I have tried checking the HTML and CSS code of the page but it seems that Elementor animates in the Back-End as I couldn't find anything.

I know that I might specify in JavaScript or JQuery the width condition in which the event is triggered but I am unable to find the source file in which the animation is stored.

If you have faced a similar problem and found a solution I would gladly read your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done form elementor. Use animation only in  desktop view by using preference of viewing site by phone or tablet then, do none animation on tablet and phone.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nitesh! Can you provide clearer instructions in your answer on how to achieve a difference in animation on desktop vs. smaller screens as this may partially answer the original poster's question.

Comment: as you know we can preview from different devices. after enabling your animation in pc preview change your preview into mobile and then default the animation, do the same for tablet. so when done animation will only occur in desktop.